# anuglar 2 ionic 2 html issues

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

i am building a chat client. One the major issue i am facing is unable to force messages to appear in next line. depending upon the size of the message it tries to fit into available space in the same line.

the html looks like:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div class="chat-container">    
        <div *ngFor="let item of items">
            <simple-message *ngIf="item.templateType == 'simple'" [data]="item"></simple-message>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

the template is:

```
@Component({
    selector : 'simple-message',
    template : `<p [ngClass]="(data.responder == 'agent')?'chatbubble':'chatbubble-reply'">{{data.msg}}</p>`

})
```

the scss is:

```
.chat-container{
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .chatbubble{
        border: 1px solid #F1F0F0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #F1F0F0;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        float: left;
        max-width: 80%;
    }

    .chatbubble-reply{
        border: 1px solid #0084FF;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #0084FF;
        color: white;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        float: right;
        max-width: 80%;
    }
```

i tried replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following CSS solutions and let me know:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

[Documentation for overflow-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap?v=example)

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

[Documentation for white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space?v=control)

Using CSS3:

```
.chatbubble:after { content: ' '; display: block; }
```

[Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#x18)

**Update:**

Why don't you try adding a `<br>` to your template?

```
template : `<p [ngClass]="(data.responder == 'agent')?'chatbubble':'chatbubble-reply'">{{data.msg}}</p><br>`
```

Comment: using css3 it does throw it to the next line but not in the begninning of the line. just below where previous one finishes

Comment: @Vik ok, that's something. The main goal we achieved it. Now, have you tried with some margin or padding top class to create space between new and previous messages?

Comment: @Vik Actually, we could add it to the existing rule! `.chatbubble:after { content: ' '; display: block; padding-top: 10px; }`, for example.

Comment: i tried like:
.chatbubble:after { content: ' '; 
      display: block; 
      float:left}

Comment: @Vik Did it work? Anyways, I'm glad we solved the main issue of your OP. Now, you just need to add CSS rules to the CSS3 rules that I posted until you get the desired layout. :P

Comment: well no tht doesnt work. and the issue is partially solved only. the layout still looks ugly as i see every new line start below previous line

Comment: hmmm... Try `.chatbubble:before {...}`.

Comment: @Vik man... I think you have to add: `white-space: pre;`, or `white-space: pre-wrap;`, see which one suits you best. I'm 99% sure is this! :D

Comment: unfortunately none of these are working. i still see it just below in the next line